# Get n results per group laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get multiple rows using groupBy on **status** column.

With groupBy after collection, i got the data i wanted, my current queries and results screenshot below:

```
Comic::latest("updated_at")->get()->groupBy("status")->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->take(3);
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z73cc.png)

This may cause performance issue in the future because it will get all records first, and then groupBy then map. Is there an alternative way to do it in the query?

Can't post image directly because it requires 10 reputations, sorry and thank you!

**Edit:** Found a solution using window function ROW_NUMBER(), thanks @apokryfos and @Mihai

```
Comic::latest("updated_at")
->fromSub('select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status) as RowNumber from comics', 'x')
->where('RowNumber', '<=', 3)
->get();
```

Comment: You might be able to rewrite this query as a raw query using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). I am not exactly clear on how you can do this. I *think* something like `SELECT <cols>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY status ORDER BY updated_at desc) as row WHERE row <= 3`

Comment: You can post the data as text, e.g. in a code fence `~~~json` … `~~~`, that's often even preferable over the image alone.

Comment: Look here and use db::raw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is exactly what i need, thanks

Comment: @hakre Didn't know that, will use it in the future!